# Not found "os.path.isdir" in EXE using pyinstaller

Tags: python, ecm

I try to access ECM Drive path.
and I was able to access the ECM Drive path in pycharm compiling system.
but I wasn't able to access that in EXE file using pyinstaller.

I tested something and I can't access ECM system using EXE.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS5Rb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm4a0.jpg)

What's difference?
How can I access ECM Drive using EXE file.

#### ADD Contents

I can find the path when I compile in pycharm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K24EH.png)

but I can't find the path in EXE.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7TpP.png)

and I test run compiled EXE as administrator. but result is same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVFfp.png)

---

#### Code

```
import sys, os, shutil
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import clipboard
import time

folder_path = [["U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/01.기종별프로그램/2. 보유 프로그램/2. AET (승강기식)",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/01.기종별프로그램/2. 보유 프로그램/1. AMT (다층순환식)",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/01.기종별프로그램/2. 보유 프로그램/3. ACT (평면왕복식)"],
               ["U:/전사 폴더/NAS1/Public/[000 주차현장설계도면]/[DET] 승강기식/[DET_2015이후]",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS1/Public/[000 주차현장설계도면]/[DMC] 다층순환식/[DMC_2015이후]",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS1/Public/[000 주차현장설계도면]/[DMF] 평면왕복식/[2015이후]"],
               ["U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/01.기종별프로그램/- 표준 프로그램/승강기식",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/01.기종별프로그램/- 표준 프로그램/다층순환식",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/01.기종별프로그램/- 표준 프로그램/평면왕복식"],
               ["U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/02.기종별 표준 전기도면/2.승강기식(AET)/국내/표준",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/02.기종별 표준 전기도면/1.다층순환식(AMT)",
                "U:/전사 폴더/NAS2/Control 3/02.기종별 표준 전기도면/3.평면왕복식(ACT)/DMF 전기도면(표준 BOM 전기도면)/평면왕복식 표준전기도면"]]


def copyFolder(path, file_path, fname):
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(path, file_path), os.path.join(fname, file_path))
    print("복사 완료")


def copyFile(src, fname, dst):
    shutil.copyfile(src, os.path.join(dst, fname))
    print("복사 완료")


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUI()
        self.desktop_path = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
        os.chdir(self.desktop_path)

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(800, 200, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyStock v0.1")

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)

        self.combobox = QComboBox(self)
        self.combobox.addItem("승강기식")
        self.combobox.addItem("다층순환식")
        self.combobox.addItem("평면왕복식")

        self.folderCombobox = QComboBox(self)
        self.folderCombobox.addItem("보유 프로그램")
        self.folderCombobox.addItem("주차현장설계도면")
        self.folderCombobox.addItem("표준 프로그램")
        self.folderCombobox.addItem("표준 전기도면")

        self.pb1 = QPushButton("폴더 다운로드")
        self.pb2 = QPushButton("파일 다운로드")
        self.pb3 = QPushButton("폴더 업로드")
        self.pb4 = QPushButton("파일 업로드")
        self.pb5 = QPushButton("경로 클립보드에 복사")
        self.pb_test = QPushButton("TEST")

        self.pb1.clicked.connect(self.folderDownloadButton)
        self.pb2.clicked.connect(self.fileDownloadButton)
        self.pb5.clicked.connect(self.copyClipboard)
        self.pb_test.clicked.connect(self.test)
        self.label = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        saveLayout = QGroupBox("정보")
        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.combobox)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.folderCombobox)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.pb1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.pb2)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.pb5)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.pb_test)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        saveLayout.setLayout(gridLayout)

        layout.addWidget(saveLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def test(self):
        path = folder_path[self.folderCombobox.currentIndex()][self.combobox.currentIndex()]
        print("path: ", path)
        print("path Test: ", os.path.isdir(path))
        # cnt = 0
        # if (os.path.isdir(path)):
        #     filenames = os.listdir(path)
        #     for filename in filenames:
        #         if (self.lineEdit.text() in filename):
        #             file_path = filename
        #             cnt = cnt + 1

        QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, dir=path)
        # if (os.path.isdir(path)):
        #     # 다운로드할 파일 위치 열기
        #     if cnt == 1:
        #         fnames, ftype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, dir=os.path.join(path, file_path))
        #     else:
        #         fnames, ftype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, dir=path)

    def copyClipboard(self):
        cnt = 0
        # 기본 파일 경로 확인
        path = folder_path[self.folderCombobox.currentIndex()][self.combobox.currentIndex()]

        # 해당 경로에서 lineEdit에 기록된 프로젝트 번호를 포함하는 폴더명이 있는지 체크
        if (os.path.isdir(path)):
            filenames = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in filenames:
                if (self.lineEdit.text() in filename):
                    file_path = filename
                    cnt = cnt + 1

        if (os.path.isdir(path)):
            # 경로를 클립보드에 복사
            if cnt == 1:
                path = os.path.join(path, file_path)
                clipboard.copy("내 PC/ECM Drive (U:)" + path[2:])
            else:
                clipboard.copy("내 PC/ECM Drive (U:)" + path[2:])
            print(path[2:] + "가 클립보드에 복사되었습니다.")

    def fileDownloadButton(self):
        path = None
        cnt = 0
        file_path = None
        # 기본 파일 경로 확인
        path = folder_path[self.folderCombobox.currentIndex()][self.combobox.currentIndex()]


        # try:
        #     print("(EXE)확인 결과: ", os.path.isdir(self.lineEdit.text()))
        #     os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
        #     print(sys._MEIPASS)
        # except:
        #     print("(PYTHON)확인 결과: ", os.path.isdir(path))
        #     os.chdir(os.getcwd())
        # print("찾을 위치: ", path)

        # 해당 경로에서 lineEdit에 기록된 프로젝트 번호를 포함하는 폴더명이 있는지 체크
        if (os.path.isdir(path)):
            filenames = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in filenames:
                if (self.lineEdit.text() in filename):
                    file_path = filename
                    cnt = cnt + 1

        if (os.path.isdir(path)):
            # 다운로드할 파일 위치 열기
            if cnt == 1:
                fnames, ftype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, dir=os.path.join(path, file_path))
            else:
                fnames, ftype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, dir=path)

            if fnames:
                desktop_list = os.listdir(self.desktop_path)
                cnt = 0
                for desktop in desktop_list:
                    if (self.lineEdit.text() in desktop):
                        file_path = desktop
                        cnt = cnt + 1
                if cnt == 1:  # 파일 저장위치 결정
                    dst = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, dir=os.path.join(self.desktop_path, file_path))
                else:
                    dst = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, dir=os.getcwd())

                if dst:
                    print("파일 다운로드 시작")
                    os.chdir(dst)
                    for fname in fnames:
                        copyFile(fname, os.path.basename(fname), dst)

    def folderDownloadButton(self):
        path = None
        cnt = 0
        file_path = None

        path = folder_path[self.folderCombobox.currentIndex()][self.combobox.currentIndex()]

        if (os.path.isdir(path)):
            filenames = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in filenames:
                if (self.lineEdit.text() in filename):
                    file_path = filename
                    cnt = cnt + 1
        if (cnt == 1):
            fname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, dir=os.getcwd())
            os.chdir(fname)
            if not fname:
                print("Cancel")
            elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(fname, file_path)):
                print("동일한 이름의 폴더가 있습니다.")
                self.label.setText("동일한 이름의 폴더가 있습니다.")

            else:
                print(file_path + "을(를) " + fname + " 로 복사합니다.")
                self.label.setText(file_path + "을(를) " + fname + " 로 복사합니다.")
                p = Process(target=copyFolder, args=(path, file_path, fname,))
                p.start()
        elif (cnt >= 2):
            print("중복입니다.")
            self.label.setText("중복입니다.")

        else:
            print("폴더를 찾을 수 없습니다.")
            self.label.setText("폴더를 찾을 수 없습니다.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #
    # try:
    #     os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
    #     print(sys._MEIPASS)
    # except:
    #     os.chdir(os.getcwd())

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

#### ADD

I try to run in python 3.8. the result is same with EXE file.
I think there is a difference between the pycharm project and python 3.8.

#### ADD

I confirmed when I compiled in anaconda virtual env, os.path.isdir("path") returns True, but when I compiled in python virtual Env or EXE file, os.path.isdir("path") returns False.

Comment: Not sure if that is a python problem. Did you try to run compiled EXE `as administrator`? https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2010485-software-does-not-see-mapped-drives

Comment: [Why not upload images of code or errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry. it's my first question in stack overflow. I added code and other contents

Comment: @rzlvmp Thank you for your comment. I try it, but result is same.

Comment: Could you show the error or exception as text in the question? I still haven't seen it, so I don't know if the file itself can't be found, or the `os.path` module itself can't be found.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The file itself can't be found.
os.path module activate well.

Answer (score -2):

First step you need to do in module part:

```
import os
```

Give this code to access the os module

Then in the code part:

For example You are going to access java software:

```
java = c://(#here type your software location path)
os.path.isdir(java)
```

That's all. problem fixed.
Enjoy programming